# how to change .tsv file row names in R?

Tags: r

I downloaded gene_expression.tsv file from the Internet and read it in my project in R.

After reading gene_expression.tsv, I would like to change the row names of that by below code:

#read it by below code:

```
Sarcoma_expr <- read.table(file = "gene_expression.tsv",   
sep="\t",header=TRUE)
```

# for nameing row names of Sarcoma_expr,I used below code:

```
rownames(Sarcoma_expr) <- data.frame(Sarcoma_expr$gene_id)
```

but I got this Error:

Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : invalid 'row.names' length

I appreciate if anybody shares his/her idea with me.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `data.frame()` around `Sarcoma_expr$gene_id`?

Comment: @Basibo1, Hi. No, without data.frame() I got this error:                                        Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘1-Mar’, ‘2-Mar’

Comment: Okay, according to that error there are duplicate values in the `gene_id` column, and duplicate row names are not allowed. You should get rid of those duplicates before proceeding.